# convergence of a succession of functions

Tags: real-analysis

$f_n : [0,1]\rightarrow R$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ and uniformly converges to a $f:[0,1]\rightarrow R$. I have to prove that if $f_n([0,1])=[0,1]$ then $f([0,1])=[0,1]$.
This is true if I have only pointwise convergence?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. (1) As $f$ is continuous (by uniform convergence), $f([0,1])$ is closed. So if $f([0,1]) \ne [0,1]$, there is some open $(y-\epsilon, y + \epsilon) \subseteq [0,1]$ which is disjoint from $f([0,1])$. Choose $N$ such that $\|f_N - f\| < \frac \epsilon 2$. As $f_N$ is onto, we have $f_N(x) = y$ for some $x \in [0,1]$. What can you say about $|f(x)-y|$?

(2) Think of $f_n(x) = x^n$.